# :lang: Can I use :lang or Other CSS Language Tags to Display Different Background Images in a Media Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, pseudo-class, lang

I have a Rails 5.0 application that is localized in English and Spanish. I have media queries where I display different background images depending on the orientation and max-width.

I have read the following links about `:lang`.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang

What I want to do is display different background images depending on the language. I have tried the following code.

```
:lang(en) {
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) { padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderLighthousePortrait.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) { padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderLighthouseLandscape.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
}
:lang(es) {
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (orientation: portrait) { padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderWeb-768portrait.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (orientation: landscape) { padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderWeb-768landscape.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2000px) and (orientation: portrait) { padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderWeb-2000portrait.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2000px) and (orientation: landscape) { padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderWeb-2000landscape.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 2001px) { padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/HeaderWeb.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

My next attempt.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    :lang(en) { 
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderLighthousePortrait.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    :lang(es) { 
        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderWeb-768portrait.jpg") center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
        }
        @media (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2000px) { 
            padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
            background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderWeb-2000portrait.jpg") center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
        }
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    :lang(en) { 
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderLighthouseLandscape.jpg") center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
    }
    :lang(es) { 
        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderWeb-768landscape.jpg") center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
        }
        @media (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2000px) { 
            padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
            background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderWeb-2000portrait.jpg") center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 2001px) { padding-bottom: 50px; .intro-body h1 { font-size: 500%; }
            background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nbcbigbend/HeaderWeb.jpg") center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -ms-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
        }
    }
}
```

I see a black background which is my default background color for the website. I have not found any examples of this nor have I found any prohibitions either. I have found examples for other CSS declarations that also used a lang tag in the html but none using media queries or any for background images. I have not found any documentation that says that you have to use a lang tag in your html code along with the :lang tag in your stylesheet.

Can I use `:lang` this way?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the CSS I included above and got the black background instead of my background images. When I remove the :lang tag from around the CSS it works fine.

Comment: did you put the `lang` attribute in some html node?

Comment: No that was my question. The only CSS that I want to use lang for is background images for the website. I currently don't need to reference anything in my HTML. From your question it appears that I have to use the lang tag in my HTML. If that's the case what I want to do will not work.